# XSL-FO single page layout

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

Is there a way in XSL-FO to define a single page layout? meaning that all content should be on a single page. Basically the page should be as long as the content, which is dynamic.

I'm using Apache FOP.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far that has not worked?  How much content are you talking about?

Comment: @TonyGraham The content is dynamic. I don't have anything to show as I couldn't figure out how to do it or if that even possible.

Comment: If you could do it, how would you print it? Would it be for viewing only?

Comment: You could create a document with a huge page-height. Format your document to the formatter's area tree and then examine the last content's "Y" value and set the page-height in the area tree to this value and reformat.

Comment: @KevinBrown can you give me an example of how to accomplish this?

Comment: @Wolf, unfortunately I have not worked with FOP's intermediate format. You can read up on it here:
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.4/intermediate.html

Answer (score 0):

You want a formatter that supports `page-height="indefinite"`. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#page-height)

I don't know any formatter that supports `page-height="indefinite"`. AH Formatter doesn't (https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-fo11.html#page-height). FOP says 'not yet' (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-page-height). RenderX don't qualify their support for `page-height`, so they might (http://www.renderx.com/reference.html).

Comment: RenderX does not support this either, but this can be accomplished using a simple manipulation of the intermediate format.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XSLTExtensions (https://github.com/pplcg/XSLTExtensions, https://www.w3.org/community/ppl/wiki/XSLTExtensions) from the Print and Page Layout Community Group (http://www.w3.org/community/ppl/).

Within the single XSLT transformation that generates the XSL-FO, you could:

- Make a variable for the XSL-FO for a very long page with the correct width
- Run the extension on the variable to get the area tree
- Use the extension's XSLT functions to get the height of the formatted content
- Generate the XSL-FO again with the exact page height to fit the content

You would then format the output XSL-FO.

It might be simplest to put all of your content in an `fo:block` with known ID so that it's easy to get the height of the content by getting the height of the block.

It's been a while since I used the extensions, but that's the general idea.